# Error : segmentation fault , core dumped , in c programming

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error, out-of-memory

the following  c programming code gives a core dump segmentation fault , please tell me why i am getting this error and  help me by giving a corrected version of this code .Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
    char str[100], ch;
    int i, Flag;
    Flag = 0;
 
    printf("\n Please Enter any String :  ");
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
    printf("%s",str);
    printf("\n Please Enter the Character that you want to replace with :  ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
    {
          str[i]=ch;    
      }
    str[i]='\0';
    
    printf("\n The characters have been found and replaced with %c and they occur %d times ", ch, i + 1);
    printf("The replaced string is %s ",str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The for loop must look at least like for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++). But in any case  it is unclear what the program does.

Comment: You are changing `str` inside the loop and wiping out the terminating nul character due to incorrect `<=` condition. So `strlen` overruns the buffer. Change to `<` as pointed out in previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
    char str[100], ch;
    int i, Flag;
    Flag = 0;
 
    printf("\n Please Enter any String :  ");
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
    printf("%s",str);
    printf("\n Please Enter the Character that you want to replace with :  ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) //change <= to < 
    {
          str[i]=ch;      
      }
    str[i]='\0';
    
    printf("\n The characters have been found and replaced with %c and they occur %d times ", ch, i + 1);
    //printf("The replaced string is %s ",str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a core dump has been generated, you can figure it out yourself:

```
> ulimit -c unlimited
> gcc -g -o demo demo.c
> ./demo
> ...
> Segmentation fault (Core dumped)
> gdb demo core
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/david/demo 

 Please Enter any String :  bla bla

 Please Enter the Character that you want to replace with :  s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
(gdb) where
#0  __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:181
#1  0x000055555555529a in main () at demo.c:16
(gdb) bt full
    str = 's' <repeated 100 times>
```

With a little help of the debugger you can see that the bug is at line 16. You want `<` instead of `<=` in `for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)`, otherwise you replace the trailing NUL character (`'\0'`) with `'s'` and you end up accessing outside of the bounds of the array.